# recover files from ubuntu

Tags: data-recovery

I've accidentally formatted and installed ubuntu on my ntfs partition (d drive in Windows, I wanted to install on c drive instead)which had many important data.  Now I still have my c drive, but lost the d drive. Is there anyway I can recover those files?

Comment: c an d d have no meaning in Linux. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: I installed testdisk and recovered some files using photorec from the current linux partition, but I can see another one named extended, that's also a linux partition. So I'm not sure if I've got the whole thing, plus its all scrambled, ters no order whatsoever